# SQL Server, aggregate CASE statements into one single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am in need to aggregate CASE statements in my select so they  calculate into one row. Or i don't -have- to, but it would make a better spreadsheet afterwards

My query is something like this:

```
SELECT
    me.gardsnr
    ,me.bruksnr
    ,me.festenr
    ,me.seksjonsnr
    ,COUNT(Case when be.bruksenhetstypeKode = 'A' THEN (be.bruksenhetstypeKode)  END) AS 'A'
    ,COUNT(Case when be.bruksenhetstypeKode = 'B' THEN (be.bruksenhetstypeKode) END) AS 'B'
    ,COUNT(Case when be.bruksenhetstypeKode = 'F' THEN (be.bruksenhetstypeKode) END) AS 'F'
    ,COUNT(Case when be.bruksenhetstypeKode = 'I' THEN (be.bruksenhetstypeKode) END) AS 'I'
    ,COUNT(Case when be.bruksenhetstypeKode = 'U' THEN (be.bruksenhetstypeKode) END) AS 'U'
FROM 
    Bruksenhet be
INNER JOIN 
    Matrikkelenhet me ON be.matrikkelenhetID = me.id
GROUP BY
    me.gardsnr
    ,me.bruksnr
    ,me.festenr
    ,me.seksjonsnr
    ,be.bruksenhetstypeKode
```

This returns a result along the lines of:

[image: example]

Like row nr 1 and 2 - I would like to combine these two rows into one row i.e. just one row for gardsnr = 1, bruksnr = 4, festenr = 0 and seksjonsnr = 0 - with 5 in Column 'A' and 3 in column 'U'

Hope that made sense?

Comment: `CASE` **Expression**. `Case` (`Switch`) statements don't exist in SQL Server.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, **except** those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `be.bruksenhetstypeKode` in the `GROUP BY`.  Remove it:

```
GROUP BY me.gardsnr, me.bruksnr, me.festenr, me.seksjonsnr
```

The structure of your `COUNT()`s is a bit complicated.  I normally write this using `SUM()`, so I would just do:

```
SELECT me.gardsnr, me.bruksnr, me.festenr, me.seksjonsnr,
       SUM(Case when be.bruksenhetstypeKode = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
       SUM(Case when be.bruksenhetstypeKode = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B,
       SUM(Case when be.bruksenhetstypeKode = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F,
       SUM(Case when be.bruksenhetstypeKode = 'I' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS I
FROM Bruksenhet be INNER JOIN
     Matrikkelenhet me
     ON be.matrikkelenhetID = me.id
GROUP BY me.gardsnr, me.bruksnr, me.festenr, me.seksjonsnr;
```

I would advise you NOT to use single quotes for column aliases.  That just leads to confusion.  Use single quotes only for string and date constants.

Comment: You sure are right, but you forgot a ',' and 'U'. By the way, do you know if a PIVOT would perform better here?

Comment: Thanks for exceptionally quick answer and as far as I can see that did the trick!

Comment: @Turo No, I am still not very proficient in the sql landscape, been long time since  I worked with much sql though my studies - so it feels a bit like learning by doing still :) So I didn't know there was a function for pivots in sql?